# had win7 and win dual boot, but now boots directly to win7 only

Tags: windows-8-preview, multi-boot

after installing windows 8 on another partition, when i would boot up computer it would give me the option to boot windows 8 or windows 7. this worked fine for several weeks, but for some reason it now boots directly into windows 7 with no option for booting into windows 8. i dont know what i changed to make this happen, but hopefully there is something that can be done to fix this. let me know if you have seen this or know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System properties-> Advanced tab-> under Startup and recovery click settings. A new window will open named Startup and Recovery, under system startup select your default operating system and then check both the checkbox and then try.

Comment: Does this support Windows 8? I'm not sure if it does.

Comment: I never worked in win8 and the above process need to be done in win7 which is his default OS.

Comment: My point is, I don't think Windows 8 is visible from Windows 7 due to the changes with UEFI.

Comment: So you mean we can't have win7 and win8 at the same time on the same computer.

Comment: I did not say that at all. I said that the solution you've suggested may not work because 7 is older than 8 and won't be able to modify the boot record to be 8-aware. Since you've never worked with 8 by your own admission, I don't think your answer will work at all, for the UEFI reason stated previously.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice program called [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=642) that can do this for you. Just select the partition where the windows 8 drive is located, and add it as an entry. Note: For the windows 8 bootloader support, you will need the beta version.